Already ongoing present conditions
I want to say that I will give someone a present in the future only if they're currently and already regularly helping other people. How should I do that?

I will give you a present if or provided you help other people

You tell me that my 1 example implies future help. So, how to achieve my stated meaning?

As ever, context. As a general principle, you should forget about using provided, and stick with if unless and until you learn enough to know why you need the less common word. Your example could refer to present OR future help, depending on context. If you needed to disambiguate, you could force the "present help" sense with ...if you are [currently] helping other people. Which you wrote yourself anyway - you just failed to correctly use the continuous participle.

I like the way you have presented the question with a desired meaning!

By "currently and already" do you mean as of the time you are making that promise? So the potential recipient of the gift must be someone who is helping others "now"? They have been helping people prior to your making the promise of a gift.

"provided", "only if", "as long as" are all OK ways to express the proviso. There's no reason to forget about "provided".  It is hardly an uncommon word.

You wouldn't condition your future action on a past activity of someone else unless you were uncertain of that past activity. If the person must have been helping others before your promise is uttered, you're basically asking for proof that they have been helping others.  "... provided you supply evidence that you have been helping others before now [the time of this promise]".  On the other hand, if you do indeed know that they have been helping others, your promise of a gift would be "because you have been helping others"  not contingent upon them helping others.

If you want to condition a future action on your part on a history of actions by someone else, as long as they continue to act as they have been acting prior to the time of your making the promise:

I will [do something] provided you continue to [do what you have been doing heretofore].

or

I will [do something] provided you have continued to [do what you have been doing heretofore].

heretofore is synonymous with "up until now", where "now" is the time of the utterance (the making of the promise).
If you're not looking for formal language but colloquial language, use "up until now" instead.
The first version is prospective.  The second (better) version is retrospective from a point in time in the future, the time of your future contingent action, the time when you would be called upon to fulfill your promise.


I'll give you a present if you currently help other people and do so in the future.

Future in main clause, simple present in the if clause.
